# LINQ Query in Junction Table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that looks like this :-

```
CategoryId | QuestionId
----------------------- 
1      |      2 
1      |      3 
3      |      2 
4      |      3
```

I need to pull out all of the Questions that are not in use by a specific category. so for eg, CategoryID = 1.

The result should be that there are no questions to display.

Anyone know the best way to do this? so far i've not got anywhere with it.

EDIT **

```
public partial class FAQ
    {
        public FAQ()
        {
            this.FAQCategoriesFAQs = new HashSet<FAQCategoriesFAQ>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastUpdated { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FAQCategoriesFAQ> FAQCategoriesFAQs { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class FAQCategory
    {
        public FAQCategory()
        {
            this.FAQCategoriesFAQs = new HashSet<FAQCategoriesFAQ>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DomainId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastUpdated { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FAQCategoriesFAQ> FAQCategoriesFAQs { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class FAQCategoriesFAQ
    {
        public int FAQCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int FAQId { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public virtual FAQCategory FAQCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual FAQ FAQ { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have entities with navigation properties?

Comment: yes,  x.FAQCategoriesFAQs.. but i need to ignore the questions where they are being repeated by other categories?

Comment: "I need to pull out all of the Questions that are not in use by a specific category. so for eg, CategoryID = 1" Should that be "question ID =1"? So you want questions that don't appear in that junction table anywhere? Otherwise I'm confused about what you are asking for. If it is questions not in that table then I assume you can get a list of the question IDs that do exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have navigation property for categories in `Question` entity:

```
db.Questions.Where(q => !q.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == id))
```

UPDATE Thus your junction table differs a little bit from your original question :)

```
db.FAQs.Where(q => !q.FAQCategoriesFAQs.Any(qc => qc.FAQCategoryId == id))
```

Comment: I have to access the junction table directly I'm afraid. Its not ideal, but is something we had to change. So i cant access the Categories navigational property. I have to access the junction table which is whats making it difficuly.

Comment: @Derek can you provide your entities code as well (show ids and navigation properties). Also why you forced to use junction table? Is there other fields besides keys?

Comment: Yes, there's a sort order column added to the junction table, which broke the navigation properties.

Comment: @Derek updated, you can use `FAQCategoryId` from your junction entity